# Get device physical size using CSS3

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an HTML5 page using CSS3 and SVG graphics in development.  I tried using media queries to enlarge the SVG graphics when the device pixel ratio is 1.5 or 2.  This works fine.  Now I view my page on a small device like the Motorolla Xoom.  The reported ratio is 1.  This means the Xoom displays everything quite small as compared to a regular monitor.  The most annoying part is that it looks great in landscape mode, but in portrait mode the full page is resized to fit in the same width.  The ratio number does not change at this point.

I did try using something like 'width: 3in;' but again, it was only the correct size in landscape.

Ultimately, I'd like to use some ratio of device size vs pixel size, and scale everything this way.  Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "'width: 3in;' ... was only the correct size in landscape"?  Was it three inches wide in landscape but not three inches wide in portrait?  If you want to fill the whole width why are you not just using percentages?

Comment: I am not using percentages because a 1900x1600 screen is physically bigger than an iPhone.  I simply want my SVG graphics to be readable.  They are charts and gauges, etc.  Going across the screen, I'd want 1 on an iPhone portrait, and 2 in landscape.  I'd want 3 on a 1024x768 screen on a desktop.  Maybe 5 or 6 on a large screen.  My problem is that pixel count can't help me.  And when I do "3in" for size, I get three charts going across my Android tablet in landscape.  They look good.  When I flip it to portrait, I still get three charts, and they are too small.

Comment: Are you not using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)?

Comment: My OP states that I am.  That only gets me resolution which again does not help.  A 1024x768 resolution is found.  iPad?  PC monitor?  The sizes are FAR different.  So the chart will appear too small on the iPad or too large on the PC monitor.

Comment: It only gives you resolution if you base your queries on resolution, in my previous comment I was really thinking [about `aspect-ratio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#aspect-ratio) since you were talking about your problem coming when you rotate the screen.  But I also don't think messing around with device pixel ratio is going to help you either because your problem seems to be the size of the device pixels.  There has been a lot of discussion about this on CSS WG list, read [the thread starting here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Feb/0627.html)

Comment: Yes, the issue with aspect-ratio is that My Motorolla Xoom and my HTC Sensation report a 1.  My iPad does display a 1.5 which does help, but the other devices don't help.

Comment: `aspect-ratio` is unlikely to be `1`, it'll be `16/9` or `9\16`.  There's also ['orientation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation).

Comment: Sorry, I read that wrong.  I used pixel-density to account for the iPad. You are correct that I can use aspect-ratio or orientation. Still not sure how it helps. If my chart is 300px wide, I get three across the screen in both landscape (expected) and in portrait (issue). In portrait mode, the device should have 768 width and therefore only be able to display two. It shrinks everything and shows three. If I set them larger than 300px in portrait, then my desktop browsers enlarge too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My issue was that my graphics were never rendered again when orientation was changed.  When I hit refresh again, all is coming up as expected.  This was an issue that existed somewhere between my keyboard and my chair.  The media queries are in fact working, I just need to rerender some stuff upon orientation change.